# How do i Implement Notification Badge With RecyclerView in Android Application?

Tags: android, notifications, android-recyclerview, badge

I want to count the onclick() of button in RecyclerView. But it Does not visible in Notification TextView.

Comment: full code of adapter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [increment counter which click of button in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918372/increment-counter-which-click-of-button-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but you can add boolean `item.hasnotification()` for whether display or not the badge and `item.getNotificationCount()` for displaying numbers in it